# I can not #include <gloox/inbandbytestreammanager.h> in gloox

Tags: c++, xmpp, file-transfer, gloox

I can not include `inbandbytestreammanager.h` in NetBeans it says not such directory. 
My code is following:

```
#include <gloox/inbandbytestreammanager.h>
```

I'm using Ubuntu. Is it problem with my gloox library?
So I can not use this code

http://camaya.net/api/gloox-0.9-pre5/classgloox_1_1InBandBytestreamManager.html

Comment: Can you include any other gloox header files, or is it just this file it can not find?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Yes I can include other files. Something like #include <gloox/client.h> works.

Comment: And if you check inside the gloox header file directory (wherever that is), do you see the `inbandbytestreammanager.h` file? If not maybe you haven't installed Gloox properly?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  I installed it as sudo apt-get install libgloox-dev and do not now how I had been installed and there is not such file in ./gloox/ folder. What may I correct it? Can I just add it by myself?

Comment: Are you trying to include `<inbandbytestreammanager.h>` (as in the question title) or `<gloox/inbandbytestreammanager.h>` (as in the question body)?

Comment: @juanchopanza  As in a question body, like #include <gloox/inbandbytestreammanager.h> but in gloox folder there is not such file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that class has been removed from newer versions, see [the docs for version 1.0](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0/annotated.html).

Comment: Yes, they did it:( But now I have problem with how I'm going to work without registerInBandBytestreamHandler :( Thank You.